# attrTween typescript issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I'm following along a d3 tutorial while adjusting it to accommodate typescript and react and am running into a problem with attrTween

```
selection
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(this.state.data)
        .attr("x", d => this.x(d.name)!)
        .attr("height", 0)
        .attr("y", this.graphHeight)
        .attr("width", this.x.bandwidth())
        .attr("fill", "orange")
        // .merge(selection.selectAll("rects"))
        .transition()
        .attrTween("width", this.widthTween)
        .duration(500)
        .ease(easeLinear)
        .attr("y", d => this.y(d.orders))
        .attr("height", d => this.graphHeight - this.y(d.orders));
```

in `.attrTween("width", this.widthTween)`

i am getting a Type '(t:number) => number' is not assignable to type '(t:number) => string'

here is `widthTween` function

```
widthTween = () => {
    let i = interpolate(0, this.x.bandwidth());

    return (t: number) => {
        return i(t);
    };
};
```

Comment: Why not just return it as a string like TypeScript wants you to?  `return i(t) + '';`  It's going to end up as a string in the DOM anyway.

Comment: you don't need attrTween if you init `width` to 0 and transition it to `this.x.bandwidth()`

Comment: yeah i knew that, but that is what the tutorial provided and i just followed along, it was also sort of an introduction into arcs

Comment: You should take @Mark’s advice and convert the return value to a string. The type definitions require the value to be a string because that’s exactly what’s specified in the API docs for [`.attrTween()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_attrTween): *“The interpolator must return a string.”*.

Comment: it's exactly what i did. Thanks Mark! idk how to upvote or mark as answer :p

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem, but as people said you should force your tween function to return a string, you can see in this overload of the `attrTween` method:

`attrTween(name: string, factory: ValueFn<GElement, Datum, (t: number) => string>): this;`